# Javascript Design Pattern Prototype error for web3.js

Tags: javascript, prototype

Don't know what I am doing wrong, created a javascript prototype for a web3js application I am working on. When I try calling the function in the prototype it is not seeing the function in it. Throwing "persona.testing() is not a function" when I check the console.log.

```
Web3 = require('web3');

if(typeof web3 != "undefined")
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
     else {
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
     }

var initweb3 = function(address,abi) {
        this.address = address,
        this.abi = abi;
        this.contract;
        web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
        this.contract = web3.eth.contract(this.abi);
        this.contract = this.contract.at(this.address);
 }

var paddress = "0x0",
    pabi = "",

    maddress = "",
    mabi = "";
    persona = new initweb3(paddress,pabi);
    //minion = new initweb3(maddress,mabi);

persona.prototype = {

testing: function(){
  console.log('Yes, I know');
},

testing1: function(){
  console.log('No, I don't');
}
};


persona.testing();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `prototype` when you want to create one or more instances of a function.

in your case `initweb3` is a constructor function.
make sure your constructor function starts with uppercase letter.

For example:

```
  function Person(){ /*...*/ }
  Person.prototype.sayHi = function() { };

  const p = new Person();
  p.sayHi();
```

in your use case `persona` is already an instance `object`, if you want to add a new function to it you simply do `persona.testing = function() {}`

OR

You can also try extending the `initweb3` function.

```
initweb3.prototype.testing = function(){ /* code goes here */}
.
.
. 
persona.testing();
```

Watch this video to learn more about prototypes in JavaScript.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=riDVvXZ_Kb4

Comment: thanks for the reply. A situation where I have more functions and want to include all using the shorthand I used above, how do I do it cause I tried it above but not recognising the function. Edited my code to include more function in order to be clear.

Comment: @CharlesOkaformbah replace `persona.prototype` with `initweb3.prototype` and you should be good.

Comment: @CharlesOkaformbah you are missing a comma in your example. `initweb3.prototype = {

testing: function(){
  console.log('Yes, I know');
}, 

testing1: function(){
  console.log('No, I don't');
}
};`

Comment: Cool, thumbs up if you are happy with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Object.assign

```
persona = Object.assign({}, persona, {
  testing: function(){
    console.log('Yes, I know');
  }
});
```

or

```
persona.prototype.testing = function(){};
```

Comment: ok. but will like to know what I am possibly doing wrong in the code. I have also tried persona.prototype.testing and it gives me Can not set property of undefined. I also have other methods in the prototype which I removed so that the code will not be bulky, thought the method are not working like this one too.

Comment: Try peorsona.testing = function(){};
For single function might be ok, but for multiple functions, i would use Object.assign

Object.assign takes 3 parameters:
1) Template - empty object literal in our case
2) Target object, which we are extending
3) New object, which gets attached with n number of methods